# The value of attribute "content" associated with an element type "meta" must not contain the '<' character. error in blog

Tags: html

The value of attribute "content" associated with an element type "meta" must not contain the '<' character.

Comment: Please add more information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others and explain how/where you get that error message.

Answer (score 0):

As <> are HTML delimiters for tag (such as `<p>my paragraphe</p>`) if your text contains this value it can make an error with the tags (such as `<p>my <paragraphe</p>` can be see as an error).

Maybe sharing the code will help us to give you the correction to do.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question it should be added as a comment